# Scan url scheme ios

Tags: ios, dictionary, navigation, url-scheme

Correct me if this question is a duplicate. I tried but couldn't find an answer.

Basically, I want to implement the same feature that applications like AroundMe and NearMe have: when users found a location, they can then click "Navigate here" and the app can tell show them all the navigation applications they have on their phone and they can pick their favourite one to go forward.

I know we have this api to check if an URL scheme is available:

```
- (BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

But how do I scan to list all the navigation apps that I can call and the format of each?

Do I need this information available in the app database beforehand?

If YES, where should I look for the url format of each app?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

This information is usually up to the export/sharing/document controller. You will not be presented with the list yourself, but the API will show the menu for you in a popover or action sheet. This means you can't manipulate the list, only tell it to go open in SOMETHING.

Comment: So far I have used UIDocumentInteractionController to open a pdf document only. Are you saying that using the same controller with a URL like http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f will prompt users to choose a navigation app?

Comment: There is a URI type for routing and maps. What does opening the URL on the app do for you?

Comment: The destination of my app is not to open a URL but to show users navigation apps that they can choose to use, and opening the custom URL scheme of a navigation app can lead users to that app directly. I.e: users are shown with a list including tomtom, google maps, apple maps, if they choose tomtom, they will then be led to tomtom with pre-filled start location and destination.

Comment: Ok I see. To be a little more specific: If you find out which apps have THEIR OWN URI schema, you can embed that as a list, but it is less than elegant, perhaps add a downloadable list or template so the app can be updatable. You would query each URI if it can be opened and provide a list for the ones that can open.

Comment: e.g. Sygic has one: com.sygic.aura://coordinate | lon | lat | type